# Order by date column ASC and delete top row for particular name

Tags: python, mysql, sql

Columns are `Name`, `Score`, `Date`.
I want to sort one name by `date` and delete the oldest record using python and sql.
I tried :

```
cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM "+group+" ORDER BY date ASC LIMIT 0, 50000;")
cursor.execute("DELETE FROM "+group+" WHERE '_rowid_' = '1';")
```

group is a variable for the table name. When this runs it runs without errors but nothing is deleted.

Comment: Please don't use `+` to concat sql queries. You might become a victim of sql injection. See xkcd 327 for reference

Comment: `'_row_id_'` is a string, due to the single-quotes, which never will match `'1'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Quotes around `_row_id_` makes it a *string*. In other words the query would try to delete records where string `_rowid_` equals to string `1` which is never true and nothing is deleted as a result.

Omit the quotes to let it be recognized as a column name:

```
myid = 1
cursor.execute("DELETE FROM "+group+" WHERE _rowid_ = ?;", (myid, ))
```

Also, generally speaking, you *should not be using string interpolation or string formatting to make SQL queries*. But in this case, you are *parameterizing a table name* which cannot be inserted into the query through query arguments by a database driver.

Comment: it works, however only once. The next time it comes to delete nothing gets deleted. I presume this is because its trying to delete row 1 which already is deleted. Is there a way to shift all the data up to fill row 1 again. Sorry new to sql.

Comment: @EdwardJinks it sounds like you have a variable with a dynamic id value which you need to insert into the query - is that correct?..

Comment: @EdwardJinks if this is a case, I've updated the example code in the answer - should give you a hint.

Answer (score 1):

[MySQL DELETE statement](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/delete.html) supports `ORDER BY` and `LIMIT`, so you can delete oldest by date row with simple statement:

```
cursor.execute("DELETE FROM "+group+" ORDER BY `Date` LIMIT 1;")
```